# Virtual File Name too long

Tags: bash, file, virtual

I'm using the `<()` on bash to create virtual files. I'm basically dumping strings into it so I would get  `<(contents of string)`, however, the strings are too long and I get this error

```
:error:0200103F:system library:fopen:File name too long:bss_file.c:391.
```

Any suggestions on how I can prevent this when creating the virtual file?

Comment: Show your code. I bet you're using process substitution wrong.

Comment: Oh, I'm doing it programmatically and the library is doing some sanitation, otherwise it actually should work.

Comment: "it should work", except it's not. Show your code.

Comment: The syntax is not `<(contents of string)`. It's `<(command that produces string)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably writing something like

```
my_command <(foo bar baz)
```

when you should be writing

```
my_command <(printf "%s\n" foo bar base)
```

The process substitution runs a command whose output is treated as the contents of a file; it does not simply provide the contents as a sequence of strings.